# Can questions tagged with [yii] have PHP's syntax highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

Many askers set the [yii](/questions/tagged/yii) tag without the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag. Can questions with this tag also be automatically colorized with PHP's syntax highlighting?